# How to identify variables introduced by the Tseitin encoding in z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I need to count the number of solutions of a bitvector theory. I would like first to bit-blast and then call a (propositional) model counter on the resulting CNF. However, in order for the count to be equal to the number of solutions of the original theory, I have to perform the so called projected model counting (due to the added Tseitin variables). The problem is that I haven't been able to identify the correct subset of variables (those that are not added by the Tseitin encoding) that is required for this task. This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
F = z3.parse_smt2_file(inst)
g = Goal()
g.add(F)

t = Then('simplify', 'bit-blast')
subgoal = t(g)

vars = z3_util.get_vars(subgoal.as_expr())

t = Tactic('tseitin-cnf')
subgoal = t(subgoal.as_expr())

print_cnf(subgoal)
```

Where 'vars' is the subset of variables that I need. However, when I print the CNF to a file and I run a tool performing projected model counting using those variables, the number of models returned is not correct. Any idea on how to get the correct subset of variables? (i.e how to exclude the Tseitin variables)

Comment: The tseitin-cnf tactic does more than just straight-forward tseitin translation. See comments here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/core/tseitin_cnf_tactic.cpp Do you have a small enough example that would allow us to track where those extra variables came from?